# QSplitter: How to make second column smaller?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qsplitter

In QtCreator I created a QSplitter which separates vertically a QTreeWidget from a vertical layout with many things on the right.

I would like that this second column by default takes the minimum space it needs to maximise the first one.

I tried setting sizes and vertical policy of the splitter as expanding but surely I'm not doing it right. How can I set this exactly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set this in code with `QSplitter::setStretchFactor(int index, int stretch)`.

You would set the first column to have a stretch of 1 and the second 0.

```
splitter->setStretchFactor(0, 1);
splitter->setStretchFactor(1, 0);
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to set such a property in QtDesigner? Editing the contents in a too small column is annoying...

Comment: @leemes Sorry, I don't use QtDesigner, I can't help with that

Comment: 1 and 0 work; but for some reason, other values (like 2,3 for a 2:3 ratio) won't work. Any idea, why?

Comment: For the ratio (at least in python) you have to use values from 0-100 ... i.e. 20 and 80!